# questions on graph data structure: set of tuples vs dict

Tags: python, dijkstra

The following code where I used set of tuple to build the graph, would return -1 (solution exists but returned wrong -1):

```
def findCheapestPrice(self, n, flights, src, dst, K):
    """
    :type flights: List[List[int]]
    :type src: int
    :type dst: int
    :type K: int
    :rtype: int
    """

    # NOTE: Here I use a set
    g = collections.defaultdict(set)
    for s, d, cost in flights:
        g[s].add((cost, d))

    q, distance = [(0, 0, src)], {}
    heapq.heapify(q)
    while q:
        cost, stop, city = heapq.heappop(q)

        if stop>K+1 or cost>distance.get((stop, city), float('inf')): continue

        if city == dst:
            return cost
        for nbr, c in g.get(city, ()):
            if c+cost < distance.get((stop+1, nbr), float('inf')):
                distance[(stop+1, nbr)] = c+cost
                heapq.heappush(q, (c+cost, stop+1, nbr))
    return -1
```

But if I change the graph data structure to dict of dict, the code works. I've thoroughly checked the differences but still cannot find an answer. What caused the differences?

```
def findCheapestPrice(self, n, flights, src, dst, K):
    """
    :type flights: List[List[int]]
    :type src: int
    :type dst: int
    :type K: int
    :rtype: int
    """

    # NOTE: Here I use a dict
    g = collections.defaultdict(dict)
    for s, d, cost in flights:
        g[s][d]=cost

    q, distance = [(0, 0, src)], {}
    heapq.heapify(q)
    while q:
        cost, stop, city = heapq.heappop(q)

        if stop>K+1 or cost>distance.get((stop, city), float('inf')): continue

        if city == dst:
            return cost
        for nbr, c in g[city].items():
            if c+cost < distance.get((stop+1, nbr), float('inf')):
                distance[(stop+1, nbr)] = c+cost
                heapq.heappush(q, (c+cost, stop+1, nbr))
    return -1
```

Comment: Please add a test case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
g[s].add((cost, d))
```

This is how you initialize your data structure when you use tuples. You can index your dictionary with `s`, which is your city, and you'll output a set of tuples. Each of these tuples has `cost` as the first element.

When you iterate over it like this:

```
for nbr, c in g.get(city, ()):
```

`nbr` is your `cost` since it was the first element in your tuple.

```
g[s][d]=cost
```

This is how you initialize your data structure when you use a dictionary. Keep in mind that here you use `cost` as your value.

When you iterate over it like this:

```
for nbr, c in g[city].items():
```

`c` is your cost, since `nbr` is associated with the key and `c` with your value which is the cost.

In summary `nbr` and `c` get mixed up. In the variant with tuples, the cost is assigned to `nbr`, while in the variant with dictionaries, the cost is assigned to `c`.